# avfoundation error. Cannot detect list_devices

Tags: ffmpeg, avfoundation

I need to get ID for current screen and, [as it said here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#avfoundation), I tried to get list of all available input devices...

Whith command `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ''`

It works fine on two my Mac but on the third, with OSX 10.7.5 it does not works:

```
$ ./ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ''
ffmpeg version 3.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
...
Unrecognized option 'list_devices'.
```

I got

> Unrecognized option 'list_devices'

there and don't know how to fix it. Could you help me with that?

Like I understand this situation, there is issue with avfoundation. It just doesn't works correctly...

From another side it gives me error:

> Unknown format 'avfoundation'

```
$ ./ffmpeg -h demuxer=avfoundation
ffmpeg version 3.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
...
Unknown format 'avfoundation'.
```

**UPD:** issue was in **ffmpeg**. That version what I used just does not support interaction with avfoundation

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -h demuxer=avfoundation` and see the list of options available.

Comment: @mulvya ...here issue not with keys but with avfoundation. For some reason I cannot interract with it at all

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in ffmpeg. That version just does not support interaction with avfoundation